# Error building Postgres and "... must have a working 64-bit integer datatype"

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, bundle

When I entered this:

```
$ sudo bundle update
```

An error occurred:

```
An error occurred while installing do_postgres (0.10.17), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install do_postgres -v '0.10.17' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

so I tried to install do_postgres:

```
sudo gem install do_postgres
```

It failed, so I checked log file. It showed the error like the following:

```
In file included from /usr/include/postgresql/postgres.h:47:0,
                 from conftest.c:3:
/usr/include/postgresql/c.h:284:2: error: #error must have a working 64-bit integer datatype
 #error must have a working 64-bit integer datatype
  ^~~~~
```

I have no idea how to solve it. Could someone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: 64-bit ints are standard since about C89 or C99 (if I recall correctly). Something else is causing configure to fail. Show the whole conf test in question.

Comment: This might help: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/mingw-users/thread/4EA17E67.4080804@users.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already solve it. The problem was due to wrong version of postgres.h not 64 bit int...